# 2005 Suzuki Reno S wipers and fluid

Tags: suzuki, windshield-wipers, windshield

I recently filled up my windshield washer fluid and was wondering two things.

How do I operate my rear wiper?

Is there a separate reservoir for fluid for the washer fluid for the rear windows or does it use the same one as the front window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rear washer runs off the same bottle as the front. There are two dedicated washer motors which force fluid each way. If you are experiencing problems with the rear not washing, there is a check valve at the reservoir where the rear line attaches to it (off the bottom of the tank). This valve sometimes gets clogged and does not allow fluid to go through. Also, ensure you are using de-icing agent if in cold weather area to prevent the lines from freezing.

As for operation of the pump, you would pull the wiper controls to bring fluid to the windshield and push it away from you to operate the washer on the rear. The wiper will work continuously while you push on the control, then for a period of time after you let off of the control (though the washer will quit spewing). Hope this answers your questions.